# Custom Asterisk auth

Tags: asterisk

I'm gathering info for a project i'm working on, we wanna link our system with an asterisk server, one of the things i'm looking for is a module that can "hook" on the iax2 auth process, what i intend is to use other server to do the auth stuff (like, user sends user/pass to asterisk, asterisk sends it to a server B, server B process it and answers YES/NO, and so asterisk answers to the user YES/NO. Is this possible with a module or should i modify the asterisk-core?

Answer (score 0):

With IAX, you can optionally include dialplan ON ANOTHER SERVER. The other option would be to call the other server and let the second server handel the rest of the call.

Comment: sorry it wasn't what i was looking for, i had to create a daemon to listen for the auth and then write the proper config asterisk files)